# import LocalImg from '../src/images'

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

import LocalImg from '../src/images'

error:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

it clearly says that you have not include index.js file, so it was not sure what you want to import from that many files.you have to solutions

1. use require to get only what file you need i.e. if I need *ad1.png* I will do it the following way

> const ad1 = require('../src/images/ad1.png');

1. will add an index.js file in images folder and do something like this

```js
//index.js

export const ad1 = require('./images/ad1.png');
.
.
.
export const ad2= require('./ad2.png'); 
export const ad3 = require('./ad3.png'); 
export const ad4 = require('./images/ad4.png');


//in other file I should import like

import {ad1, ad2, ad3....} from '..src/images';
```